# How to Fake a process to be the child of another

Tags: linux, process

Program A (ReportHandler) calls program B (Specific Report). In order for me to get my "specific report" I need to go through program A, which then calls program B and gets me my report. My problem here is that Program B has a "security" measure that checks for program B to be a child process of program A. (This is because program A makes sure no-one else is running this program B, makes sure it gets run between x and y hour of the day, or other programs that may interfere with the running of program B, etc.)

Program A & B are C based, but I cannot (must not) change them. I checked the code and I cannot pass parameters to program A to run B from console.. SOOO, the only idea I have left, is to try and "trick" the system so that program B shows up as a child of program A so that I can run it from console.

The reason for me to try and automate this, is that I need to dial into a dozen servers each day to get this report... I want to centralize this script so that I can remotely ssh this script to each server and be done with it. would save me an hour of my day. or more.

#### Check being made

```
if ( TRUE != child_of_Program_A() )
    {
    epause( win[MAIN], 1,
    _("This Program Must Be Run From Program A"));
    return( FAILURE );
}
STATIC BOOL child_of_Program_A()
{
    FILE *fp;

char statname[32];
pid_t ppid;
char proc_name[32];
char buffer[128];
char *ptr;

ppid = getppid();

while(ppid != 1)
    {
    snprintf(statname, sizeof(statname), "/proc/%d/status", ppid);
    if (NULL == (fp = fopen(statname, "r")))
        {
        return(FALSE);
        }

    proc_name[0] = '\0';
    ppid = -1;

    while (NULL != fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp))
        {
        if (NULL != (ptr = strtok(buffer, STAT_SEP)))
            {
            if (strcasecmp(ptr, "name") == 0)
                {
                if (NULL != (ptr = strtok(NULL, STAT_SEP)))
                    {

                    if (strcmp(ptr, "Program_A") == 0)
                        {
                        fclose(fp);
                        return(TRUE);
                        }
                    strncpy(proc_name, ptr, sizeof(proc_name));
                    }
                }
            else if (strcasecmp(ptr, "ppid") == 0)
                {
                if (NULL != (ptr = strtok(NULL, STAT_SEP)))
                    {
                    ppid = atoi(ptr);
                    }
                }
            }
        if (ppid != -1 && proc_name[0] != '\0')
            break;
        }

    fclose(fp);
    }

return(FALSE);
```

Comment: Cannot answer without knowing more about the "security check". Running `strace` on B, noting down what happens before it fails, and then comparing to what shows up when B is run from A might help.

Comment: harsh to ask... but have you consider loading a using ld_preload to interrupt the syscall used for verification and just providing a heuristic response based on attributes of program A / B before returning a valid albeit false response?

Comment: why don't you ssh-run the program A (report handler) ? is it because A is graphical and not easily scripted?

Comment: @jop. The security measures vary a lot depending on the report... Program A makes calls to all available reports. Depending on the report is the security check. Since it is a standard to have all reports routed through this "portal" for the sake of higher management access, my low level sys admin self needs to work harder to get to my reports. Also, the program itself (which I have access to the code and to recompile, but I can't due to policy) checks for the PPID of Program B.. if the PPID of program B hits '1' before hitting a PID where program A exists, then it just exits.

Comment: @OlivierDulac It is not what I would call graphical.. not in this era, but it does require the user selection of at least three sub-menus to get to the option that actually calls program B.

Comment: @jop. I just re-read your question, I have updated the initial post to show the check.

Comment: @MattJoyce Not harsh.. not to me anyway.. I have never heard of ld_preload, and hence not sure how to fully use it. I just did some research and looks like you can throw a library to precede the load of other libraries. I'm unsure of how you would throw the response to program B.

Comment: you can use ld_preload to interrupt system calls.  so you could capture the getpid() query... and perform your own logic in the shared library.  sort of do a match up of the two processes on your own then return a false answer in the event it's the controlled condition you are looking for.  otherwise perform a standard getpid with response.  it's generally a pretty dangerous maneuver and frowned upon.  but it might work well here.

Comment: @Fredog: maybe you could get aroudn by starting A via `expect` (and have an expect script doing the "get down 3 menus to launch B" part)

Comment: or ... as the procedure seems to check that its parent program is called "Program_A" : have a C program with the same name but placed in a different directory invoke program B ? ie   `scp Program_A user@desthost:/tmp && ssh user@desthost /tmp/Program_A` ? (or in the same dir, if the original "program_A" is somewhere else)

Comment: @OlivierDulac I had this same crazy thought yesterday night after a cup of "tea". I just tried it and it works. Can't believe I was breaking my head trying to fake Process ID's.. I'm however intrigued into trying Matt's ld_preload method a go, just for the sake of learning. Thanks to all for your time and input on this (quote from jim mcnamara) "very unusual thing".

Comment: @Fredog : hey, it helped that you added the check itself. One very important thing in debugging or ressource asking : state what you want to do, but not how you want it done ^^ Usually, a better statement of the facts and the result wanted leads to a better/faster solution than trying to implement the solution one had in mind (it's true in many areas of IT : lots of time clients say "I want to use this program in that way to do: that" instead of "I need to do: that" and most of the problems start there...). Have a nice day (and keep on having crazy thoughts ^^)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand - you are making this harder than it needs to be.  Automate navigating the menu maze.
Unless you really want to try the very unusual thing you asked about - consider this alternative.

Going into program A in a non-interactive way will solve the problem.  `scp` a shell script to each of the servers, in your account. The shell script can be a here document.  `stdin` becomes the script, in place of the keyboard.

Pretend that you have a transcript of a correct interactive session with Program A  and it looks like this:

```
cd /foo
./programA username
password
A
/deviceA/catalog.txt
B
A
13 cows
now
```

The script using a here doc looks like this

```
#!/bin/ksh
cd /foo
        ./programA username<<EOF
        password
        A
        /deviceA/catalog.txt
        B
        A
        13 cows
        now  
EOF
```

You may have answers that are unique to each remote server, incorporate them.  scp the correct file to each remote server.

```
ssh remote_server 'cd /foo && chmod +x ./myscript.sh
```

This sets execute permissions.

On your local desktop create a simple script.sh

```
ssh remote1  './foo/myscript.sh'
ssh remote2  './foo/myscript.sh'
ssh remote3  './foo/myscript.sh'
```

This script.sh now runs your report with no intervention from you. I am also guessing you may not have set up ssh keys on the remote servers - this allows passwordless access like the script above would want to have.

http://rcsg-gsir.imsb-dsgi.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/documents/internet/node31.html

Comment: you may have to put everything between <<EOF and EOF on the first column, to be sure the shell doesn't add extra spaces/tabs in front of things such as passwords, etc?  (not 100% sure it is needed in *every* shells)

Comment: Thanks Jim. I do have my SSH keys in place, and what I was trying to avoid is making 6 scripts to go by Program A (6 different scenarios), in order to execute Program B which does not require but a single parameter.

Comment: Well, if it now takes one hour per day, and you spend two hours automating after 30 days you are way ahead.  Time-wise.

Comment: I definitely agree Jim. The reason I try to stay away from the main handler is because every time a business user requests a new report (or they make a report obsolete), there may be changes on the options of said handler so I would have to update all the scripts to reflect this. My sincere apologies for not being thorough with what I had tried and why, but the question would be too lengthy. Also a sincere appreciation for the answer provided.